# avrdude7.2 unable to detect atmelice - works with avrdude6.3

Tags: avrdude

I have been using avrdude6.3 on windows 10 and 11 without issues.

But lately we needed support for ATTINY1626, so upgraded to v7.2

While 6.3 works (detects atmelice) , v7.2 says unable to detect the atmelice

used ZADIG to change the driver to libusb

Error with v7.2 :
[image]

Same PC same drivers only exe and config file v6.3:
[image]